# How can i Split words inside this .txt in c#

Tags: c#

My question is how can i split the words inside this .txt file

```
string filePath = @"..\..\Tekst.txt";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Here is how i want to split it. I want it to split every time there is space, ",", ".", "!" and "?". But when i do that it comes out with an error

```
        string[] wordsArray = lines.Split(' ', ',', '.', '!', '?');

        foreach (string line in wordsArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Comment: What does the contents of `Tekst.txt` look like? Can you post a few sample lines along with desired output/result?

Comment: "*Here is how i tried to split inside it*" so what happened, did you get an error, did you pc catch fire?

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: I got an error when i tried to split it but i can read the entire file.

Comment: share the sample content and how you want to split? the question need to share more details

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no accessible extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Carbon BLack C:\Users\drama\source\repos\Carbon BLack\Program.cs 22 Active

Comment: That's because `lines` is a `List`, not a `string`. Only strings have a split method. Probably you need to loop through the lines and run `split` on each individual line.